# How to solve an equation with modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I got an equation $e = a * b$ mod $p$ and I want to solve this equation for a.

I thought it must be something like:
$a = e/b$ mod_inv $p$

Can you provide me a link where I can learn to do things like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to calculate the inverse of $\;b\pmod p\;$ , for example: since $\;2\cdot4=1\pmod 7\;$ ,then $$4=2^{-1}\pmod 7\implies e=2a\pmod 7\implies a=e\cdot2^{-1}=4e\pmod7$$

Comment: So the right solution is: $a = modinv(m) \;(mod p)\; $ ?

Comment: I've no idea what "modinv(m)" is.

Comment: Sorry I'm more a programmer than a mathematican... Modinv for me is the modulo inverse. So modinv(m) is the modulo inverse of m. I think my comment above is wrong. It should be: $m * modinv(b) (mod p)$

Comment: @Pe Ok, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation solved for a looks like this:

$a = e * modinv(b) % 7$

Modinv(b) for me is the modulo inverse of b. I don't know how mathematicians write it so...